# controlling a loop in qt on button clicks

Tags: c++, macos, qt, signals-slots

I am new to Qt and I am trying to run a loop that will update a QWidget using QPainter. In short, I am trying to run an infinite loop that refreshes a QWidget on a button click (say **start game**). Then I want to stop the loop on click of another button (say **end game**). I would also like to hear about any better approach to obtain this functionality.

In my MainWindow class, I want to start a thread which contains the object of a class Game. An infinite loop starts when game->start_game() method is called. I want to start the loop on a button click. Then the loop should exit on click of another button "end".

```
//main_wid is the central widget of my MainWindow
QPushButton* btn_start = new QPushButton("start", main_wid);
QPushButton* btn_end = new QPushButton("end", main_wid);
//thread, game are private variables in my MainComponent class
thread = new QThread;
game = new Game(10);
game->moveToThread(thread);

//on btn_start click, the thread start in run_thread() method
connect(btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(run_thread()));
//on thread->start(), I call start_game() slot in the Game class which runs an infinite loop
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), game, SLOT(start_game()));

//here i want to connect clicked(bool) of btn_end to a method in game class 
//such that i can break the loop in start_game() method.
//.......??
```

My game class:

```
class Game : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
Game(int n);
~Game();

public slots:
void start_game();
void end_game();

signals:
void finish_game();

private:
int num;
};
```

Definition of Game class methods:

```
Game::Game(int n)
{
    num = n;
}

void Game::start_game()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
    cout << "game loop started:" << i++ << endl;
    }
    //emit finish_thread();
}

 void Game::end_game()
{
    cout << "*************************end**************************" << endl;
    emit finish_game();
}

Game::~Game()
{

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _in the question itself_.

Comment: done! thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Your triangle is drawn at `z=-2`. Since you seem to never set a projection matrix, it will be left at identity and OpenGL will clip anything which is lying outside of the range `[-1,1]` along all three dimensions (and no matter what angle you rotate it, since it will rotate around theo rigin, it will always stay 2 units away from the origin).

When you are learning OpenGL you should be aware that most of the GL functionality you are using is *deprecated* since almost a decade. In modern GL, these functions are completely removed. Your book seems horribly outdated. I can only advice to learn modern OpenGL instead.